# Telegram, Telebot, Python3, Генератор случайных чисел

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота в телеграм на с помощью библиотеки telebot.
Задача бота отправлять рандомные цифры в чаты где был запрошен старт и продолжать это до тех пор, пока не получит стоп-слово.

Проблема в том что бот перестает реагировать на стоп слово и спамит бесконечно сообщения, если его запустить в двух и более чатах.

```
reqList = actions.getRequestModelList(message.from_user.id)#запрос с БД
for reqX in reqList:

    if reqX.chat_ID == message.chat.id:
        
        if message.text == 'go' and message.reply_to_message.text[0:10] == 'Кто желает' and \
            message.content_type == 'text'\
            and member.status == 'creator':

            global w, Flag
            Flag = False

            if len(message.reply_to_message.text) == 106:            
                w = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Поехали:')
                        
                    
    if req.token != None and w!= None:
        
        actions.recordEditMessageID(req, w.message_id) #запрос с БД
        
        if message.content_type == 'text' and w.from_user.id == 1092520486 and w.text[0:7] == 'Поехали':
            i = 1
            
            nums = ''
            data = json.load(open('{}.json'.format(req.token)))

            while Flag == False:
                global m, msg

                if message.reply_to_message == None:
                    return None                         

                if message.reply_to_message.message_id == w.message_id and 'стоп' in message.text:

                x = random.choice(NUMS1)
                bingoNums.append(x)
                time.sleep(6)
                nums = nums + str(x) + ', '

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, x)
                bot.edit_message_text(w.text + '\n' + nums, message.chat.id, req.bingoMsgID)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Запускайте в отдельном потоке/процессе. Я бы на Вашем месте использовал [`apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/background.html#module-apscheduler.schedulers.background).

Comment: Перефразировал вопрос, добавил код который сейчас есть. Посмотрите пожалуйста, если сможете помочь, буду благодарен.

Comment: @АдильНогаев так в чём проблема с кодом? В чём вопрос?

Comment: @dim0n Проблема в том что бот перестает реагировать на стоп слово и спамит бесконечно.

Comment: @АдильНогаев укажите это в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо) забыл)